# import util in Python3

Tags: python, module

I am trying to use blockchain.com API. With the following link.
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python/blob/master/blockchain/statistics.py
Could you help me to understand the error please?

My code:

from blockchain import statistics
from . import util
import json

```
def get(api_code=None):
    """Get network statistics.

    :param str api_code: Blockchain.info API code (optional)
    :return: an instance of :class:`Stats` class
    """

    resource = 'stats?format=json'
    if api_code is not None:
        resource += '&api_code=' + api_code
    response = util.call_api(resource)
    json_response = json.loads(response)
    return Stats(json_response)
```

The error:

```
  File "explorer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import util
ImportError: cannot import name 'util' from '__main__' (explorer.py)
```

Comment: `if api_code is not None:` can be simplified to  `if api_code:`

Comment: I have a hunch about this but I prefer to read how do you wrote your code and what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to use the blockchain api library and to do so you copy part of the statistics module in your own script?